# Display javadoc and code completion

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, javadoc

I just stared using Android studio and I'm having some issues with displaying javadoc.

I normaly use Netbeans IDE and there once you press `.` key you get code completion popup with javadoc like shown on this screenshoot: [image: Netbeans]

But in Android Studio it just shows code completion popup. It works if i press `Ctrl + Space`
[image: Android Studio]

Is there any setting to enable the same behaviour as in Netbeans?

Here are my android studio settings:
[image: Settings]